# ValueError: Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I have a data-frame as below named as data.
| CHS      | POF       | COF  |REF_COF| per_COF |
| :------: |:--------: |:----:|:-----:|:-------:|
| 4.72     | 0.00134   |116114|74352  |160      |
| 4.34     | 0.00134   |74352 |847100 |100      |
| 7.20     | 0.02      |678904|45670  |70       |
| 10       | 0.2       |23456 |38089  |88       |
| 5.84     | 0.04019   |125678|54351  |200      |
| 8.94     | 0.90101   |908522|967387 |38       |

I want to add another column named 'CI' in this existing data-frame, by taking the help of a column named 'per_COF'.
When I do this I get desired results,

```
for key, value in enumerate(data['per_CoF']):
    data.loc[key, 'CI'] = find_CI(value)
```

However, to avoid loops in my program when I do this I'm getting a value error. find_CI() is a function that takes one input and gives the respective CI value.

```
data['CI'] = find_CI(data['per_CoF'])
```

Error Description:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This seems silly mistake but I'm not able to figure it out kindly help.

Comment: Use `data['CI'] = data['per_CoF'].apply(find_CI)`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I will check this.

Comment: It's not working. find_CI() is a function it takes one input

Comment: do you check dupe? `data['CI'] = data['per_CoF'].apply(find_CI)` is same like `data['CI'] = data['per_CoF'].apply(lambda x: find_CI(x))` - both takes one input and gives respective CI value